# Garbled error page output using Gzip in ASP.NET / IIS7

Tags: asp.net, gzip

I've implemented [Rick Strahl's GZipEncodePage](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2007/Feb/05/More-on-GZip-compression-with-ASPNET-Content) method on my site and it works great for the site itself.  However, when my code throws an exception the "Server Error" page looks something like this:

[image: garble garble]
<sub>(source: [x01.co.uk](http://x01.co.uk/garbled_garble.gif))</sub>

I've tried to hooking into `Application_Error` in an effort to remove the GZip headers but to no avail.  How I can reverse the GZipping on error?

Answer (score 21):

I'm understand that this question is really outdated.

On Application_Error remove Filters from Response, like this

```
 protected void Application_Error(Object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    HttpApplication app = sender as HttpApplication;
    app.Response.Filter = null;
 }
```

Hope this helps anybody.

Comment: For anyone wondering *where* exactly to put this code ... dumping it into `Global.asax.cs` works wonders.  It also prevents you from needing to remember to inherit from a specific class (as per Vaibhav's answer) because it is used application-wide.  Succinct, effective, perfect.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4548466/319980 suggests using app.Response.Filter.Dispose() rather than just assigning it to null.

Answer (score 3):

In my case I put this in the my basepage class like so:

```
public class BasePage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected override void OnError(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnError(e);
        System.Web.HttpContext context = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;
        if (context != null && context.Response.Filter != null) 
            context.Response.Filter = null;
    }
}
```