# convert text to json

Tags: asp.net, json, json.net

i use Newtonsoft.Json.Net20.dll

Html

```
<div id="a" runat="server">

</div>
```

Code

```
   string kb = "a";
   string b= Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(kb).ToString();
   a.InnerText = b;
```

in local host on iis6 show `"a"`

but on internet show

��G�[�!�{��u^Ӹ�SY�L?��qz�Z�Ŕ�?���U1k������)f�]A�(�ݣ�w N����Q�x�.�0�=�����X�y6�?��.�r�~;��[�t�~�/�K��z�|�-��W�ź��Q��&���4B��Q�4o�u��x|wrt�L�K�$���Ms�.��4��ٺ.��|�.����s����W�$��_���ӗe�54��ȯ��`�6mk�@�.*��by�ap٤Z��Oa�^�s�jӪ.��p� �n�Y>�������Ӽ͊�����n�|1~M����z�r�}�Qz�9��u��i��v���0�-ˑǃ�������/���s��t���:b�������*l�~�H[�4��o'�g�/�E�=����o�� ��3G��ގ}Yߝ|�~�����H�Z�;�����i��vrg�z�m����]�Uh�Z6>[.�� )�er����I�*��.��.�K_yȞF(C�v�Ha>"s�4��gE����G�/a׮֓��r^5m��u�<ϊzZ������jVM�߷��d���x���/\N�ա�b� qo�֜��%� $���l����s?/��

[This link](http://iranfairco.com/example/test.aspx)

but

when use Newtonsoft.Json

```
       Dictionary<string, string> companyProducts = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        companyProducts.Add("product" + item.IdProduct, item.NameProduct.ToString());
        string JsonCompany = JavaScriptConvert.SerializeObject(companyProducts);
```

this code work fine.

[this link](http://www.iranfairco.com/MainPP.aspx?idCompany=142705220021)

when site upload to internet for add new reference.
Enough that copy dll to appcode

**Edit**

use gzip in gloabal.asax

void Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpApplication app = sender as HttpApplication;
        string acceptEncoding = app.Request.Headers["Accept-Encoding"];
        Stream prevUncompressedStream = app.Response.Filter;

```
    if (!(app.Context.CurrentHandler is Page ||
        app.Context.CurrentHandler.GetType().Name == "SyncSessionlessHandler") ||
        app.Request["HTTP_X_MICROSOFTAJAX"] != null)
        return;

    if (acceptEncoding == null || acceptEncoding.Length == 0)
        return;

    acceptEncoding = acceptEncoding.ToLower();

    if (acceptEncoding.Contains("gzip") )
    {
        // gzip
        app.Response.Filter = new GZipStream(prevUncompressedStream,
            CompressionMode.Compress);
        app.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Encoding", "gzip");


    }
    else if (acceptEncoding.Contains("deflate") || acceptEncoding == "*")
    {
        // defalte
        app.Response.Filter = new DeflateStream(prevUncompressedStream,
            CompressionMode.Compress);
        app.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Encoding", "deflate");
    }
}
```

Comment: There is most likely something that is completely unrelated to the JSON conversion that is wrong, as not even the `div` tag show up in the page source.

Comment: when site is uploaded how add new reference

Comment: copy dll to appcode is Enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file that you are getting from that page is a compressed file that contains an error page with an exception in it. Why it is doing this I don't know. Your global error handler might have a bug in it that causes it to send compressed data without the correct headers...

I assume you can get the file information out now you know what it is (I just right clicked on the link above and then used 7zip to open the file).

The key points though are:

**Source File:**  c:\inetpub\vhosts\iranfairco.com\httpdocs\test.aspx.cs    **Line:**  20

```
[VerificationException: Operation could destabilize the runtime.]
   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter..cctor() +6

[TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter' threw an exception.]
   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter..ctor() +0
   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextWriter..ctor(TextWriter textWriter) +16
   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Object value, Formatting formatting, JsonSerializerSettings settings) +157
   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Object value) +9
   test.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\inetpub\vhosts\iranfairco.com\httpdocs\test.aspx.cs:20
   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +14
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +35
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +99
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +50
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +627
```

Comment: I think there is a problem with using comrpession filters on error pages. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4548221/mvc-3-compression-filter-causing-garbled-output deals with this issue too it seems. The solution there may work for you to get you a proper error message page. I should note that this only half answers the question of why you are getting the garbage. It doesn't address why you are getting that exception in the first place but hopefully now you know you'll be able to sort it yourself...

Comment: @GodIsLive: I got the information as I described in my answer. The file returned is actually a gzipped file containing an html page. I suspect it was telling the browser it was plain text and so the browser attempted to render it and wrapped it in a little bit of standard HTML. Just download the file directly as I mentioned above and you should be able to unzip and find the full file. Or of course you might be able to use info from the recent comment to stop it being compressed if you are using the response.filter to do the compression.

Comment: Well, the question I linked in my first comment should help you solve the display issues you are having. I have no idea about the json encoder though since I've never used the newtonsoft software.

Answer (score 0):

There is most likely something that is completely unrelated to the JSON conversion that is wrong, as not even the `div` tag show up in the page source.

Analysing the response in a binary editor reveals a lot of the UTF-8 sequence `EF BF BD` which is the character `FFFD` which is the [Unicode replacement character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm). This is used when Unicode decoding fails, most likely because you have tried to decode something with the wrong encoding.

Comment: I went down the same line of thought as you initially but I think when I did a save as while viewing the page it saved the converted file instead of the real downloaded file. If you right click on the file and click save as you'll notice there is no HTML and the first few bytes seem to match up to a gzip comrpessed file.